# \lstinputlisting does not respect the \lstset 'float' option

Tags: listings

How can I force `\lstinputlisting[...]{filename}` to obey *all* parameters set by `\lstset`?  (Note the `float` option given to the TeX example, but not to the LaTeX example.)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{helloworld.tex.example}
Hello, World!
\bye
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{helloworld.ltx.example}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  Hello, World!
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{float,frame=lines}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lstinputlisting[language = TeX, float, caption=A \TeX\ example]
                {helloworld.tex.example}
\lipsum[2]
\lstinputlisting[language = {[LaTeX]TeX}, caption=A \LaTeX\ example]
                {helloworld.ltx.example}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation says about `float`:

> makes sense on individual displayed listings only and lets them  float.

Thus it might be a feature, that option `float` cannot be set globally.

Nevertheless, the following workaround seems to work:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{float}
\makeatletter
\let\lst@floatdefault\lst@float
\makeatother
```

Comment: So basically, this is by design? How strange. Thanks for the workaround!

Comment: I don't understand that either. It would make perfect sense for me to have all my listings floating.

Comment: @rbs That's a question for the package author.